# Best directory for data exchange between PHP and MariaDB on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mariadb

On my server with OS Ubuntu 22.04 is running:

- Apache ver. 2.4.52 ... the processes running as user "www-data"
- PHP ver. 8.1.2
- MariaDB ver. 15.1  ... the processes running as user "mysql"

My PHP script will create a file "/path/myfile.txt" and call SQL command:
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/myfile.txt' INTO TABLE MyTable`

What is your suggestion: where to create "path" for this file?
Apache and MariaDB run on the same machine.
I know, that "www-data" should have read and write access.
Is it enough that user "mysql" will have read access only?

What are the best practices? Where it the best place in Ubuntu directory to create this path?

Comment: Why are you using 'LOCAL' if they are on the same server? Omitting seems more logical. MariaDB doesn't have a version 15.1 (yet). What does `select version()` show? What does `select @@secure_file_priv` show ([ref](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#secure_file_priv)). What group/other permissions does the file uploaded have? See [systemd notes about suitable directories](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/). The `mysql` user only needs read access to `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: sudo mariadb --version returns:
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (aarch64) using  EditLine wrapper